# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/94/10213294/html/ROOTNAME/videopage/settings.php on line 6

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

so please excuse my ignorance, but after thorough research I can't seem to find the answer as to why my video site is not working... This is the error message I keep getting:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/94/10213294/html/ROOTNAME/videopage/settings.php on line 6

This is the code:

```
define('BUSINESS_NAME', 'The Biz Inc');
define('BUSINESS_CONTACT', '6222 8989 8988');
define('BUSINESS_ADDRESS', '123 Story Street Anywhere NY 11218');
define('MAIN_HEADLINE', 'You Are Turning Away A Large Portion Of Your Customers<br />They Want Speed & Simplicity.<br />Don't You...?');
define('SUB_HEADLINE', '(Watch the short video presentation below...)');
define('DISPLAY_FORM_DELAY', '1000');
define('CALL_TO_ACTION', 'Enter Your Details Below To<br />Receive Your Sample Mobile Website...');
define('PRIVACY_MESSAGE', 'Your privacy is 100% guaranteed.<br />Your information will only be used to contact you regarding this service.');
```

Can anyone please help me find the solution to what is wrong with line 6? If I am being vague it's because I don't know what other information you might need. Please ask me and I will supply any details needed.

Newbie thanking you in advance for your help. help!

Comment: Note the changes in the color highlighting on your sample code. You've got a missing/extra `'` in there somewhere, causing a string to run long or get terminated early. e.g `Don't`

Answer (score 5):

```
define('MAIN_HEADLINE', 'You Are Turning Away A Large Portion Of Your Customers<br />They Want Speed & Simplicity.<br />Don't You...?');
```

The apostrophe from "Don't You" needs to be escaped. Right now it thinks that's the end of the string, and then some undefined symbols (or T_STRING) follows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your `'` by using the `\` character. If you use a code editor or an IDE with syntax highlighting it should help you avoid such errors. Just look at how the Stack Overflow syntax highlighter has found your problem above!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and making it simple for me to understand! I'm up and running : )

Answer (score 1):

**In:**

```
define('MAIN_HEADLINE', 'You Are Turning Away A Large Portion Of Your Customers<br />They Want Speed & Simplicity.<br />Don't You...?');
```

**Change:**

```
Don't
```

**to:**

```
Don\'t
```

**Here is the complete line of code:**

```
define('MAIN_HEADLINE', 'You Are Turning Away A Large Portion Of Your Customers<br />They Want Speed & Simplicity.<br />Don\'t You...?');
```

The apostrophe needed to be escaped.

Remember to do the same with any other characters that need escaping, if you plan on adding or changing text in future cases.

You can also consult the following link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character
on the subject.

And these links may be of help/interest for future use:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

---

`stripslashes()`
From the PHP manual:

**Return Values**

Returns a string with backslashes stripped off. (\' becomes ' and so on.) Double backslashes (\) are made into a single backslash ().

---

**Footnote:** If a string comes from **user input**, then this function could prove to be useful.

Comment: WOW! Thank you Fred for your help - what a great community : ) It now works and is up and running smoothly.

Comment: @user2501536 You're welcome, glad it worked out for you.

Comment: @user2501536 Any of the answers given are good. Please click checkmark to the left to accept one of the answers in order to mark it as being solved. Cheers